# Pokedex on Angular 17

Tags: angular, typescript, angular17

I'm studying into a Boot Camp and one of past challenge was create a Pokedex with pokeapi. I over the challenge and now I'm going to fix some thinks.
I have a strange problem when I'm into details of the single pokemon. When into interpolation I put the various propriety I don't get a problem, into screen stamp it but console log give me and error.

```
detail.component.ts:79 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at DetailComponent_Template (detail.component.ts:26:12)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11223:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12746:13)
    at detectChangesInView$1 (core.mjs:12970:9)
    at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (core.mjs:12933:5)
    at detectChangesInComponent (core.mjs:12922:5)
    at detectChangesInChildComponents (core.mjs:12983:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12796:13)
    at detectChangesInView$1 (core.mjs:12970:9)
    at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (core.mjs:12933:5)
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [DetailComponent],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{ this.pokemonDetails.name.toUpperCase() }}</h2>
      <img
        src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/home/{{
          pokemonId
        }}.png"
        alt="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/home/{{
          pokemonId
        }}.png"
        height="100"
      />
      <div>
        <p>Pokemon type:</p>
        <p>{{ this.pokemonDetails.types[0].type.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ this.pokemonDetails.types[1].type.name }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>
          Description:
          {{ this.speciesDetail.flavor_text_entries[0].flavor_text }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>BASE STAT:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p>HP:{{ this.pokemonDetails.stats[0].base_stat }}</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>ATK:{{ this.pokemonDetails.stats[1].base_stat }}</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>DEF:{{ this.pokemonDetails.stats[2].base_stat }}</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>S. ATK:{{ this.pokemonDetails.stats[3].base_stat }}</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>S. DEF:{{ this.pokemonDetails.stats[4].base_stat }}</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>SPEED:{{ this.pokemonDetails.stats[5].base_stat }}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: ``,
})
export default class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemonId!: number;
  pokemonDetails!: Pokemon;
  speciesDetail!: Species;

  public service = inject(StateService);

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.pokemonId = params['id'];
      this.service.getPokemonById(this.pokemonId).subscribe((pokemon) => {
        this.pokemonDetails = pokemon;
        console.log(this.pokemonDetails);
      });
      this.service
        .getPokemonSpeciesDetailsById(this.pokemonId)
        .subscribe((pokemon) => {
          this.speciesDetail = pokemon;
          console.log(this.speciesDetail);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Pokemon, PokemonResults } from '../../model/pokemon';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StateService {
  private pokemonListSubject: BehaviorSubject<Pokemon[]> = new BehaviorSubject<
    Pokemon[]
  >([]);
  public pokemonList$: Observable<Pokemon[]> =
    this.pokemonListSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchPokemonList(offset: number = 0, limit: number = 20): Observable<void> {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`;
    return this.http.get<PokemonResults>(url).pipe(
      map((data: PokemonResults) => data.results),
      mergeMap((pokemonResults) =>
        this.fetchDetailedPokemonData(pokemonResults)
      ),
      map((detailedPokemonList) => {
        this.pokemonListSubject.next(detailedPokemonList);
      })
    );
  }

  private fetchDetailedPokemonData(
    pokemonList: { name: string; url: string }[]
  ): Observable<Pokemon[]> {
    return forkJoin(
      pokemonList.map((pokemon) => this.http.get<Pokemon>(pokemon.url))
    );
  }
  getPokemonById(id: number): Observable<Pokemon> {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Pokemon>(url);
  }

  getPokemonSpeciesDetailsById(id: number): Observable<any> {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url);
  }
}
```

[image]

I hope someone can help me because some pokemon display and some no! i'm going crazy to found the problem!

```
<h2>{{ this.pokemonDetails.name?.toUpperCase() }}</h2>
```

I try somethings like this but orange alert appears. I'm newbie into the world of programming.

Answer (score 0):

The issues are happening as it tries to find some information from a null object and throws. My guess is that your template is trying to load the template before `pokemonDetails` is fully defined, and so it cannot find the values of certain fields.

You can wrap your template in `*ngIf` to not show until the value is defined:

```html
<div *ngIf="this.pokemonDetails">
  ...
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use nullish operators to only go deeper in an object if the object is defined, ie.

```html
      <div>
        <p>Pokemon type:</p>
        <p>{{ this.pokemonDetails?.types[0]?.type?.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ this.pokemonDetails?.types[1]?.type?.name }}</p>
      </div>
```

Keep in mind that your template loads immediately and your service does not. The layout in the interim needs to be able to understand what to show.